# How to preserve '+' sign in params in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have an uri like this `/store?email=google+@gmail.com`. Since '+' sign is allowed in email address, I need to preserve the plus sign. However, in rails 5, if I use `params[:email]`, I get `google @gmail.com` instead. How to prevent rails from converting '+' into space? I know we can first encode the url, and then decode it to preserve the '+' sign, but can I directly use `params` instead of extracting params from uri? Is there a way to preserve the plus sign in `params`?

Also I tried using `URI.decode_www_form_component params[:email]` ,which still didn't work. And since the url is provided by external source I can't ask them to  explicitly encode `+` as `%2B`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: How are you using that URI? Some things will URI escape, others will not.

Comment: @Schwern I didn't directly use that URI, instead I use the hash `params` to get the parameter `email`

Comment: "*And since the url is provided by external source I can't ask them to explicitly encode + as %2B*" You could give them an informative error message like "the email `google @gmail.com` is not valid". They'll figure it out.

Comment: @Patrick did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm running into the same problem and haven't found an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's up to the users of your API to properly URI encode their parameters.

`+` is a [URI reserved character](https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986#reserved) and has a special meaning, it's how you encode a space. If users want to send a literal `+` they must URI encode it as `%2B`. `@` is also reserved and it should be encoded as `%40`, though it might slip through.

They need to send you `/store?email=google%2B%40gmail.com`. Rails will decode it for you and `params[:email]` will be `google+@gmail.com`.

If you try to "fix" their mistake your application will not be behaving correctly and it will just cause more problems.

> *And since the url is provided by external source I can't ask them to explicitly encode + as %2B.*

You're not asking them, they should already know how the standard works. Somebody got sloppy on their end.

Provide them with a useful error message and they'll figure it out.

```
email `google @gmail.com` is not valid
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems `@` is correctly preserverd but `+` is not.

Comment: @Patrick Replacing `+` with a space is correct behavior for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because spaces are not allowed in URLs. A `@` might slip past. The details of exactly how escaping works get a bit complex. Rule of thumb is to percent escape any non-alphanumeric data. Better yet, use a library that does the escaping for you. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type